# Compute the probability that of the $10$ years with the highest temperatures over the last $100$ years, $9$ occurred in the last $11$ years

Tags: probability

“From data on global average temperatures over the last $100$ years, it turns out that of the $10$ years with the highest temperatures, $9$ occurred in the last $11$ years.” Compute the probability for this to happen, under the assumption that these highest temperatures are distributed randomly over the $100$ years.

Not a clue how to start or how to approach the problem.

Comment: The problem comes from the selection of example. What happens if we look at the last $20$?  (No, I am not denying the reality of what used to be called global warming, a term that fell out of fashion.)

Comment: "*under the assumption that these highest temperatures are distributed randomly over the $100$ years*". This is an extremely unrealistic assumption.

Answer (score 3):

the number of ways to choose $11$ years randomly is $\binom {100}{11}$.

How many of those happen to contain exactly $9$ out of the $10$ hot years?  Well, there are $10$ ways to choose the nine hot years and then we just have to choose two years from the ninety cold years.  Thus $10\times \binom {90}2$.

Therefore the probability that a randomly chosen list of $11$ years happens to contain exactly $9$ of the hot ones is $$\frac {10\times \binom {90}2}{\binom {100}{11}}\sim 2.828\times 10^{-10}$$

Unsurprisingly this is effectively $0$.

Note:  it might make more sense to compute the probability that your randomly chosen $11$ years contains at least $9$ of the ten hot ones, instead of exactly $9$.  In that case you must add $90$ to the numerator as there are exactly $90$ lists of $11$ years which include all ten hot years (this has little effect on the ratio, but still).

Comment: Thanks For the answer but can you point me the theory behind your calculations because I am not familiar with the notation. If it happens you know the book Statistical data analysis by Gowan in which section are those math?The term in(..) is not known to me.

Comment: I don't know that book, but the notation I used refers to the binomial coefficient, often used in combinatorics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) .  you can express it using factorials as $\binom nk=\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.  The rest of the argument is simple counting...easy, I think, if you are used to this sort of thing.  this might be a good introduction http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs/ch04.pdf

Comment: For instance:  let's just count the number of subsets of the $100$ years which contain $11$ years.  First year can be anything, $100$ choices.  Second can then just be $99$ and so on, with $90$ choices for the last one.  That looks like there should be $100\times 99 \times \dots \times 90 =\frac {100!}{89!}$ choices but as the order doesn't matter we have to divide this by $11!$, the number of ways to permute $11$ objects.  Thus the answer is $\frac {100!}{11!\times 89!}=\binom {100}{11}$.

Comment: Also, this is a Hypergeometric Distribution. You have a population of size $N$ with $K$ special items, and take a random sample (without replacement) of size $n$ and wish to find the probability of having $k$ special items. That is: $$\mathsf P(X=k) = \frac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}\quad\text{where}\binom{R}{r} = {^R{\rm C}_r} = \frac{R!}{r!\,(R-r)!}$$

Comment: Ok I think i have enough for a start now since i know where to look. Progress :)  Thanks a lot you were very helpful